# Is there a way to escape dot notation in AngularJS groupBy expression?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using this AngularJS filter: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

I have a piece of data (JSON) involving key names containing dots, which seems to be mistaken with nested properties.

Is there a way to prevent the filter from parsing the dot notation or an alternate way to specify the name of the field used for grouping ?

Note: I can't change the way data are build from the server.

My code looks like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, values) in items | groupBy: 'category_id.name'" >
    <div class="item-row">
        {{key}}
    </div>            
    <div class="badge-row" ng-repeat="item in values">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JSON data I get from the server :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test",
        "category_id.name": "Main"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "foo",
        "category_id.name": "Other category"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "bar",
        "category_id.name": "Test"
    }
]
```

When running this code, at the moment, I am getting 'undefined' as key value.

Comment: Are you sure that's the json returned from the server? Doesn't seem like a valid json to me

Comment: have you tried '\"category_id.name\"' ? (using double quotes as in your json structure)

Comment: @eyescream : you were right, I added a couple of curly braces... appart from thtat I just checked on http://jsonlint.com/ and it says JSON is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular Filter uses `$parse`, so that you can order by fields in nested objects

I have a workaround for this problem. If it helps.

**Template**:

```
(key, values) in items | groupBy: rawProperty('category_id.name')
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.rawProperty = function(key) {
    return function(item) {
        return item[key];
    };
};
```

[**JS Bin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/feneyutoca/1/edit?html,js,output)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know if it is the best way to handle this, but it definitely works. Thanks !

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :)